# redshift sql row selection based on min date

Tags: amazon-redshift, partitioning, min

I need to extract all rows from a large data set with 30+ columnns based on the min time date, account can repeat across days and execution dates, execution id is distinct and can be thought of as a transaction.

| account | execution_id | execution_datetime | execution_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 918-46 | 2023-04-03 15:59:09 | 2023-04-03 |
| 1 | 740-a2 | 2023-04-03 15:56:09 | 2023-04-03 |
| 1 | 747-9b | 2023-04-03 15:54:09 | 2023-04-03 |
| 2 | 2bb-14 | 2023-04-03 15:54:09 | 2023-04-03 |
| 1 | 818-a5 | 2023-04-04 15:47:08 | 2023-04-04 |

Ordinarily something like this would work

```
select omd.*
 from db1 as omd
 inner join (
              select id, min(execution_datetime)
              from db1
              group by execution_date,account,id
            ) as omd1 
                on omd.id = omd1.id;
```

This is returning all records vs expected outcome.

| account | execution_id | execution_datetime | execution_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 747-9b | 2023-04-03 15:54:09 | 2023-04-03 |
| 2 | 2bb-14 | 2023-04-03 15:54:09 | 2023-04-03 |
| 1 | 818-a5 | 2023-04-04 15:47:08 | 2023-04-04 |

I'm also can envision there will be a follow-up request to group the transactions across a date range of X so that min transactions across X days will be grouped,and the output might look like this.

| account | execution_id | execution_datetime | execution_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 747-9b | 2023-04-03 15:54:09 | 2023-04-03 |
| 2 | 2bb-14 | 2023-04-03 15:54:09 | 2023-04-03 |

Looking for a solution that will hopefully support either scenario, thank you.

Comment: The reason why your query returns all rows is because you do not join the execution datetime to the min datetime identified in the subquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a job for the window function row_number().

```
select * 
from (
  select *,
    row_number() over(partition by execution_date, account,id order by 
  execution_datetime) as row_num
  from db1 )
where row_num = 1;
```

You may want to suppress row_numb from the output and to do this you will need list list all 30 columns that you want.

(sorry if there are any typos)